# Jenkins throws "java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly" when testing email notification

Tags: ssl, jenkins, https, smtp

We've recently enabled https on on a Jenkins server using a self-signed SSL certificate. After we did this, we noticed that our Jenkins jobs aren't sending email notifications anymore.

I saw in some other questions asked here that this can be solved by running `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");` and in the script console but the error still appears after a while and I'm not sure that this is the solution to the error we're having.

We are using smtp.office265.com as the SMTP server. When I test the email configuration, I am getting the error below. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? TIA.

```
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1009)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:447)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1875)
Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1880)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:648)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:585)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:537)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:739)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:870)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:282)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:739)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:870)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you set up your smtp.office265.com server to use TLS.
`SMTP Host: smtp.office365.com
SMTP Port: 587
SSL Protocol: OFF
TLS Protocol: ON`

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer to the question, but I've already found the solution and I posted the answer. I still need 17 hours before the site can allow me to mark my answer as the solution though.

Comment: that's no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running these commands in the Script Console fixed the issue:

```
System.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.office365.com")
System.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2")
```

Comment: This solution helped me on Ubuntu + Java + Apache Common Emails library. Thanks!